# dart including libraries with wrong casing in URI

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-pub, dartium

So I've been working on this project in Dart for a few months without too many big issues, until a recent update from last week seems to have broken the way libraries are included in my application.  I have an application package called 'BeerRun', with the standard lib/ and web/ directories.  In 'web' I have the main beer_run.dart file, which is included and invoked in web/BeerRun.html.  I've run pub install and pub update, but then when I run my dart application, I see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/home/kyle/dart/BeerRun/web/packages/beerrun/src/input/keyboard_input_component.dart
Failed to load a file package:beerrun/src/input/keyboard_input_component.dart
```

There are about twenty instances of this message referencing different dart source files.  The problem is that the path should be /home/kyle/dart/BeerRun/web/packages/**BeerRun**/src/input, but the browser is using all lower case path names to include this file.  This was not a problem last week, until I upgraded my Dart editor; it is now version 22223.  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you are on Linux?

Comment: Can you paste your `pubspec.yaml` file? I'm curious what the name of your app is.

Comment: Also, can you paste in the results of running a recursive ls -l from your web/ directory? I'm curious what the symlinks look like. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste in an copy of your import statement, and a screenshot of your project directories (with every subdirectory open so we can see the whole directory tree). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/home/axl/workspace/dart/Test/web/packages/test/text.dart
```

I had the same problem, solution was to include library through:

```
import '../lib/text.dart';
```

instead of

```
import 'package:Test/test.dart'
```

Version info: Dart Editor/SDK version 0.6.19_r26297